# Graph Classification Question

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking at a specific type of graph, and my google-fu has failed me. The graph $G$ is a connected unweighted directed graph where for each pair of vertices $(u,v) \in G$ the shortest path from $u$ to $v$ is unique.

What is such a graph called?

Comment: Geodetic?

http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/graphs-in-which-all-shortest-paths-are-unique answers this question anyhow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such graphs are apparently referred to as geodetic graphs, as in http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_96.html My first guess was geodesic, so I wasn't far off.

Elsewhere on the internet, USP seems to be used as an obvious acronym.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!